# Form mapped to class by different name

Tags: symfony

I would like to associate my class with the forms. Is it possible that I gave different names for forms than they are in the class? For example class have property username but I would like to be mapped in the form to input of id login

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('login', 'text', array (
            'label' => 'Login'
        ))   //<- different name mapped by login
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
    ));
}
```

`User` entity:

```
class User {

  protected username;

  //...
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible and I don't really see the purpose of doing this. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If I'm reading this right I think you might be after the `property_path` option (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path).

Comment: I have a multiple forms on one page with one controller so I check the right name property for the future process like that: if ($request->request->has('name_property')) I need different names

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You are looking for `property_path`. See http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path

```
$builder->add('login', 'text', array(
    'label' => 'Login',
    'property_path' => 'username',
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Add `'mapped' => false` option to the field which you want to have different name than it is in entity. This tells symfony that when the form will be submitted, it would not try to map that field to entity. But here, you will need to do additional work - 1. add data from entities username property to the unmapped one, and 2. when submitting the form, map manually submitted login data to the username property. These steps can be done via [Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html), like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    // Set other fields...

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, [$this, 'onPreSetData']);
}

function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm(); // The form
    $data = $event->getData(); // It will be User entity

    $form
        ->add('login', 'text', array (
            'label' => 'Login',
            'mapped' => false,
            'data' => $data->getUsername(),
        ));
}

function onPostSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    $data->setUsername($form->get('login')->getData());
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
    ));
}
```

I'm not sure why you want to do this, but I showed you one way of doing this. Another and simplier way like **qooplmao** commented would be using `property_path`.

Comment: I have a multiple forms on one page with one controller so I check the  right name property for the future process
like that:
 if ($request->request->has('name_property')) 
I need different names.